# Accessing the Facebook Check-in/out featuer?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to specifically access a users checking in and out activity via the graph or is it more or less a post to the users feed?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) you need to sign in